# How to work with the demo projects of the "C# and the MVVM pattern" book

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I have downloaded code examples of the [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01M365NCZ) from [here](https://bitbucket.org/epobb/learnwpfexercises/downloads/).

When I open the WpfDemos solution that's in the download, my solution looks like below. Each separate example in the book has its own file in the solution but they are not separate projects so I can't run them. This solution only has one project and that's the only project I can run!

[image]

My question is how can executed each of these examples? I don't understand why code is organized in this manner in one project. I am using VS2019.

Comment: Surely the book explains how to use the examples? And what do you get when you run the project?

Comment: @Herohtar It doesn't. This is a short book.

Comment: It looks like you're intended to follow along in the book and work the exercises and maybe it references those demo things somewhere along the way. If reading the book doesn't give you the answers, it sounds like not a great book.

Comment: I really liked the book, just confused why the source code is provided in this fashion. All it says about source is this: "All of the source code for the demos and do-it-yourself solutions is available at https:// bitbucket.org/ epobb/ learnwpfexercises It can be downloaded as a ZIP file, or if you installed GIT you can simply type: git clone https:// bitbucket.org/ epobb/ learnwpfexercises\ .git"

Comment: I figured it out, I can right click on the file and select "Set as startup item" but it doesn't do anything. However I can go to App.xaml and change StartupUri to the new xaml file and then it runs that fine.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I can right click on each file and select "Set as startup item" from menu but it doesn't really change anything. However I can go to App.xaml and change StartupUri to the new xaml file and then it then runs that file fine as startup file.